# How to set gradient color in app:contentScrim of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, bitmap, gradient, background-color, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have tried to set gradient color in contentScrim of CollapsingToolbarLayout but it only takes simple color

Tried with bitmap like this, but it through  `IllegalArgumentException: Bitmap is not valid`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.bar_bg);
    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    Palette.Swatch vibrant =
                            palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                    int mutedColor = palette.getVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
                    if (vibrant != null) {
                        // If we have a vibrant color
                        // update the title TextView
                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setBackgroundColor(mutedColor);
                        //  mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getDarkMutedColor(mutedColor));
                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(mutedColor));

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can be helpful collapsingToolbarLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.ThemeColor2);

Comment: @AslamHossin thanks for your comment, but its not about BackgroundResources, its about contentScrim, which are not same. I can set background form xml as well.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @JahangirKabir Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {


        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();

            collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb()));
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb()));

        }
    });
```

Comment: same result -> IllegalArgumentException: Bitmap is not valid